# Uncaught ReferenceError - Jquery Conflict

Tags: jquery

I'm running into an issue of conflicting JQuery between a sliding navigation and a slider.  Any help would be appreciated!  In Chrome Console, I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined smooth-scroll.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.sticky.js:112
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:46
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js:14
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:46
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:52
```

Here is my header:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DCC Marketing - Decatur Illinois Public Relations, Advertising, Strategic Planning, & Web Development</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen">
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/960.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css">
    <style>
        body {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
        #slides {display: none;margin-top:36px;}
        .slidesjs-container {width:1000px;height:252px;margin-bottom:-21px;}
        #slides .slidesjs-navigation {margin-top:-17px;visibility: hidden;}
        #slides .slidesjs-previous {margin-right: 5px;float: left;visibility: hidden;}
        #slides .slidesjs-next {margin-right: 5px;float: left;visibility: hidden;}
        .slidesjs-pagination {margin: 0px 6px 0;float: right;list-style: none;position:relative;z-index:1000;}
        .slidesjs-pagination li {float: left;margin: 0 1px;}
        .slidesjs-pagination li a {visibility:hidden;display: block;width: 14px;height: 0;padding-top: 14px;background-image: url(images/pagination.png);background-position: 0 0;float: left;overflow: hidden;}
        .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
        .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {background-position: 0 -14px}
        .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {background-position: 0 -28px}
        #slides a:link,
        #slides a:visited {color: #333}
        #slides a:hover,
        #slides a:active {color: #9e2020}
        .navbar {overflow: hidden}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cform.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> // sticky nav bar 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav").sticky({topSpacing:0});
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> // fancybox
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.single_image").fancybox();

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });

    $("a.group").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   900, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });

});
</script>
</head>
```

And here is the code from the body where the slider is set:

```
    <div id="slides">
    <img src="images/flash1.png">
    <img src="images/flash2.png">
    <img src="images/flash3.png">
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slides.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slidesjs({
    play: {
      active: true,
      effect: "slide",
      interval: 5000,
      auto: true,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      restartDelay: 2500,
      width:936,
      height:247
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see all these jQuery plugins...are you loading jQuery anywhere?

Comment: Move your jquery.js include to above the rest of your scripts, they need it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load "js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" before you load "js/smooth-scroll.js".

Comment: I added <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> to the top of the scripts and got this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:18
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sticky' index.html:47

Comment: msie is supported in 1.9, $.browser isn't.

Comment: Still getting an error, but we're getting closer!
'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sticky' index.html:52
(anonymous function) index.html:52
o jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2'

Comment: The js file that creates the `sticky` method isn't loading, or you are trying to use that method before loading that file.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

move this at the top. It should be included before including any other script

Answer (score 0):

Jquery javascript file should load first, so, try moving this to the top

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```